# How to colour or remove the border of a tkinter Menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, colors, menu

In Tkinter, I have been fiddling with the Menu widget, but I haven't been successful in colouring my widgets in. The border of the Tkinter Menu widget stays grey no matter what I do:

[image]

Is there no other option but to leave it grey?

Code Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New")
filemenu["bg"]="yellow"

menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean `filemenu["bg"]` or `menu["bg"]` ? BTW: `filemenu["borderwidth"] = 0` http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm

Comment: The `filemenu["borderwidth"] = 0` does not get rid of the border for me, sadly.

Comment: @furas Do you have any Idea how to get rid of it? I included an Image now.

Comment: I use Linux and I don't have no problem with border. Maybe other Menu options helps or maybe there is some useful "Themed Widget" in `tkinter.ttk`

Comment: @furas I'll take a look